# "Figure 10" caption alignment in listoffigures

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

The code below presents a minimal example of my setup. This way, as the label "Figure 10" has 2 digits for the number, the "endash" character is on top of the caption.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
    labelsep=endash,
    figurewithin=none,
]{caption}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\l@figure[2]{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{4.6em}{#1}{#2}}
\renewcommand{\p@figure}{Figura }
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{format}{#1#2  -- }
\captionsetup[figure]{listformat=format}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}
\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}
\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}
\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}
\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}
\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}
\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}
\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}
\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}
\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}

\end{document}
```

How do I resolve this? I tried to use the

```latex
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1\quad}
```

but it breaks tableofcontents alignment because of below code

```latex
\newcommand{\PosTextual}{
     \clearpage
     \pagestyle{plain}
     \def\@schapter##1{
         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}##1}
         \if@twocolumn
             \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{##1}]%
         \else
             \@makeschapterhead{##1}%
             \@afterheading
         \fi
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This left aligns the numbers and aligns the `--` etc.  The thing to remember is that `\numberline` is inside a box whose width is specified (in this case, 5.5em).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\RequirePackage[
    labelsep=endash,
    figurewithin=none,
]{caption}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\l@figure[2]{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{5.5em}{#1}{#2}}
\renewcommand{\p@figure}{Figura }
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{format}{#1#2\hfill -- }
\captionsetup[figure]{listformat=format}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}
\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}
\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}
\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}
\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}
\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}
\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}
\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}
\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}
\captionof{figure}{Title of Figure}

\end{document}
```